Where do i start learning recursion for mathematical olympiads?
I've been self studying to compete in olympiads and so far, the books i've read are mostly about one specific topic (A book about number theory only , A book about polynomials only,..) But I cannot find a book about recursions to get to know the basic starting level theory to get me started. Any help would be much appreciated.

A suggestion: add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

I always have a hard time finding free sources that give a treatment of recurrences that I like. If you are ready, jump into generating functions directly. One place is Concrete Mathematic's chapter. The main other technical tool to solve, say linear recurrences with constant coefficients, using generating functions is partial fraction decomposition.

Not sure if this is useful, but there is a textbook called "Further Pure Mathematics 2" published by Pearson, which is intended for high-school students studying Edexcel AS and A Level Further Mathematics.
It has an entire chapter that introduces recurrence relations, which may be a good place to start. Here are its contents:

Forming recurrence relations
Solving first-order recurrence relations
Solving second-order recurrence relations
Proving closed forms
Mixed exercise 4

You can probably find a pdf version of this textbook online. Here is the cover page:

Hope this helps! :)
